# CSS - break a float and a non-wrappable div

Tags: css, css-float, nowrap

Ok, this is hard to explain, I have 2 elements, a floating div and a non-wrappable div, its HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id='page'>
  <div id='left'>
    some information
  </div>
  <div id='center'>
    do not break this
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#center{
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#left{
  float:left;
}
#page{
  width: 800px;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

Result:

[image]

The container (#page) is resizable, and can go smaller, like 100px, and here is where I have my problem, the #center div keeps on the right, even when is outside the container:

[image]

I need the #center div goes under #left when container is small like this:

[image]

This is the code on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p41xh4o3/

Thank you for your help!

Comment: so you always want the #center div under the #left? I dont really understand what you are trying to do, like this? https://jsfiddle.net/p41xh4o3/1/

Comment: Not always, when #page is smaller than both childs, otherwise they are on the same line, and #center is centered on the available space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i did it using "flex", on my 3 elements, this is the CSS:

```
#left{
  white-space: nowrap;  
  flex-grow: 0;
}
#center{
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #88AA88;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
#page{
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #999;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

This is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p41xh4o3/2/

Answer (score 0):

i did it using flexbox, first you have to do `display: flex;` and `flex-wrap: wrap`  on the parent. 
like this:

```
#page{
  background-color: #999;
  display: flex; // this one makes it a flex box
  flex-wrap: wrap;  // this one tells it to wrap when all children cannot fit next to each other
}
```

Then you have to give `flex-basis: 50%` for both children of the parent:

```
#center{
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
#left{
  float:left;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

i gave them backgrounds so you can see them and see how it works. think of flex-basis as the width of the element. so if you want `#left` to have width: 30% you would do something like this:

```
#center{
  flex-basis: 70%; // notice how this one is 70% because 100% - 30% = 70%
  background-color: red;
}
#left{
  float:left;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

here is a working jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/odnecaLu/4/

i really hope i helped

Comment: can you please accept my answer if it works and let me know if it does ? thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I  don't need the left side wider than the content, so using a % flex-basis doesn't work for me, the container (#page) is resizable, and can be smaller than 100px, I did it on my answer using flex-grow property (I don't know how it works exactly).